# Which DB for Registration Form iOS?

Tags: ios

i would like to code a Registration Form + Login form for iOS. I don't know very well which DB i can use. I thought to use PHP + MySQL. Do you think is a good idea? 
Who can explain me the best option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOs app should know nothing about DB. You need to make an API in some other langulage (PHP in your case), which will work with DB.

MySQL is good option as it's free and has a lot of features.